# I don't want to push the contents when sidebar is opened in js and css. How to make it independent

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

Please find the below code CSS and JavaScript. when sidebar is opened its pushing the main content. I wanted it to be independent of it. Added the javascript code can anyone help me with this?

```js
function ExpandDrawer() {
    const drawerContent = document.querySelector(".drawerContent");
    drawerContent.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
body {background-color: powderblue;}
h1   {color: blue;}
p    {color: red;}

.drawerLayer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container .drawerContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 420px;
  background: rgb(0,125,187);
  background: linear-gradient(161deg, rgba(0,125,187,1) 0%, rgba(112,188,224,1) 100%);
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .drawerContent.active {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 85px);
  left: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 32px;
  background: rgb(0,125,187);
  background: linear-gradient(161deg, rgba(0,125,187,1) 0%, rgba(112,188,224,1) 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,125,187,1);
  border-radius: 64px 0 0 64px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle:before {
  content: '\e909';
  font-family: "font-awesome";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(112,188,224,1);
}

.toggle.active:before {
  content: '\e909';
}
```

```html
<center>
    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraphhsdgaghdhagsd asdasgdjhasgdhsagdjsagdgsa ajhdkjashdkjashdkjahjdkhasd ajhdjkashdkjahdkdjashdjkahkjdhajkdhkjshdjka
        dvjadjagjhdgajdghagdjagdgahd ajdjagdasgjdgahd
    .</p>
    <div class="container drawerLayer">
        <div class="drawerContent">
           <h3>Hi</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="toggle" onClick="ExpandDrawer()">
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>This is a paragraphhsdgaghdhagsd asdasgdjhasgdhsagdjsagdgsa ajhdkjashdkjashdkjahjdkhasd ajhdjkashdkjahdkdjashdjkahkjdhajkdhkjshdjka
        dvjadjagjhdgajdghagdjagdgahd ajdjagdasgjdgahd
    .</p>
</center>
```

can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Should make something `position: absolute` probably to make it out of flow of documet elements placement.

```js
function ExpandDrawer() {
  const drawerContent = document.querySelector(".drawerContent");
  drawerContent.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: powderblue;
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
}

p {
  color: red;
}

.drawerLayer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  float: right;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.container .drawerContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 420px;
  background: rgb(0, 125, 187);
  background: linear-gradient(161deg, rgba(0, 125, 187, 1) 0%, rgba(112, 188, 224, 1) 100%);
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .drawerContent.active {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 85px);
  left: -20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 32px;
  background: rgb(0, 125, 187);
  background: linear-gradient(161deg, rgba(0, 125, 187, 1) 0%, rgba(112, 188, 224, 1) 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 125, 187, 1);
  border-radius: 64px 0 0 64px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle:before {
  content: '\e909';
  font-family: "font-awesome";
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgba(112, 188, 224, 1);
}

.toggle.active:before {
  content: '\e909';
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraphhsdgaghdhagsd asdasgdjhasgdhsagdjsagdgsa ajhdkjashdkjashdkjahjdkhasd ajhdjkashdkjahdkdjashdjkahkjdhajkdhkjshdjka dvjadjagjhdgajdghagdjagdgahd ajdjagdasgjdgahd .
  </p>
  <div class="container drawerLayer">
    <div class="drawerContent">
      <h3>Hi</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle" onClick="ExpandDrawer()">
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>This is a paragraphhsdgaghdhagsd asdasgdjhasgdhsagdjsagdgsa ajhdkjashdkjashdkjahjdkhasd ajhdjkashdkjahdkdjashdjkahkjdhajkdhkjshdjka dvjadjagjhdgajdghagdjagdgahd ajdjagdasgjdgahd .
  </p>
</center>
```